# Using different lifetimes in struct implementations

Tags: rust

I am trying to get a better understanding of Rust lifetimes.

```
struct Name<'a> {
    arg: &'a u8,
}
impl<'a> Name<'a> {
    fn new1(arg: &'a u8) -> Name<'a> {
        Name { arg }
    }
    fn new2<'b>(arg: &'b u8) -> Name<'b> {
        Name { arg }
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between functions `new1` and `new2`? I am assuming it would matter if `arg` was `&self`? Is there any case where `new2` implementation preferred or the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two methods end up being exactly the same, but it's worth learning why. Along the way, we'll learn about lifetime coercion

One lifetime can be coerced into another lifetime if that second lifetime is shorter than (or rather, is contained by) the first. This is usually notated `'a: 'b`, to mean that the lifetime `'a` entirely encloses the lifetime `'b`. The usual terminology is that `'a` outlives `'b`. The reasoning for this coercion is that you can always make a lifetime shorter if you need to. If a reference is valid during some lifetime, then it's also valid during any shorter lifetime contained in the longer lifetime.

So with that in mind, what sort of arguments can `new1` and `new2` take? We have a fixed lifetime `'a` since the whole implementation is generic in that lifetime. However, `new1` can not only take `&'a u8`, but any `&'b u8` if `'b` can be coerced to `'a`. That is, `'b: 'a` and `'b` is longer than `'a`.

`new2` is slightly different, but it ends up having the same effect. The method is generic in the lifetime `'b` and can take any `&'c u8` if `'c: 'b`. `new2` is still technically generic in `'a`, but since it doesn't use `'a` at all, it can be ignored. That said, ignoring a generic parameter is confusing (why have the parameter at all?), so it would probably be best to use `new1` instead.

Another reason to prefer `new1` over `new2` is that it fits better with `Self`. If we try to change the outputs to `Self`

```
impl<'a> Name<'a> {
    fn new1(arg: &'a u8) -> Self {
        Name { arg }
    }
    fn new2<'b>(arg: &'b u8) -> Self {
        Name { arg }
    }
}
```

the compiler complains. Why? Now the outputs have to be `Name<'a>` and in `new2`, we're returning `Name<'b>`. This isn't coercible to `Name<'a>` unless `'b: 'a`, so we have to add that as a bound on `'b`:

```
impl<'a> Name<'a> {
    fn new1(arg: &'a u8) -> Self {
        Name { arg }
    }
    fn new2<'b: 'a>(arg: &'b u8) -> Self {
        Name { arg }
    }
}
```

[(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ffec9ffff9fd375acb94bb4078040d6)

In this case, it's pretty clear that `new1` is superior since it doesn't even need that second lifetime, but still allows exactly the same inputs.